# Expectation of squared inner product

Tags: normal-distribution, expectation

Let $a \sim \mathcal{N}(0,I_m)$ be independent and $C \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ have iid $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ entries. Fix $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. I am interested in calculating $$\mathbb{E}\left[|\langle a,Cx \rangle|^2\right].$$

By rotational invariance, I believe we may take $x = e_1$. Then the problem reduces to calculating $$\mathbb{E}\left[\langle a, c \rangle^2\right]$$ where $c$ is the first column of $C$ and follows $\mathcal{N}(0,I_m).$ I am not sure how to compute the squared inner product expectation. Without the square, we have by independence $$\mathbb{E}\left[\langle a,c \rangle\right] = \sum_{i=1}^m \mathbb{E}[a_i \cdot c_{i}] = 0.$$ Any help on the squared calculation would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is $\mathcal N(0,I_m)$? Also, rotational invariance might be true, but it seems nontrivial....

Comment: $a \sim \mathcal{N}(0,I_m)$ means that $a$ is an $m$-dimensional vector with independent $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ entries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your expectation as a nested integral.  On the outside, expectation with respect to $c$. On the inside, expectation with respect to $a$.  You can re-express the number $|\langle a,c\rangle|^2$ as the matrix product $c' a a' c$, for which the expectation over $a$ works out to $c' c$.  You can (I hope) finish the job without trouble.

Comment: thanks for the answer! I think viewing it as the outer product $c^T(aa^T)c$ helps me understand it a bit. I just want to make sure I understand the calculation. We can write the outer product as a double sum: $$c^T(aa^T)c = \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^m c_ia_i a_j c_j.$$ In the case when $i \neq j$, I believe independence gives us $\mathbb{E}[c_ia_ia_jc_j] = 0$ so the interesting case is when $i = j$. But if we take the expectation with respect to $a$, we get $$\mathbb{E}_{a}[c_i^2a_i^2] = c_i^2\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}a_i^2 \exp(-a_i^2/2)da_i = c_i^2.$$

Comment: Over all $i$, this works out to $\mathbb{E}_a[c^Taa^Tc] = c^Tc = \|c\|_2^2$ (I feel as though I could have directly used the isotropy of $a$). Then the expectation of $\|c\|_2^2$ would be $$\mathbb{E}_c[\|c\|_2^2] = \sum_{i=1}^m \mathbb{E}[c_i^2] = m$$ so $\mathbb{E}[\langle a,c \rangle^2] = m.$ Is this correct? Also, if you know of any resources that would be helpful for these types of calculations that would be awesome!

Comment: These look OK to me.  As for tricks, I don't know of a systematic list. Sometimes $\operatorname{tr} (AB) \operatorname{tr}(BA)$ helps.  For instance, $\operatorname{tr}(( c'a'ac) = \operatorname{tr}(a'acc'))$....

Comment: I was thinking of resources that would help more with understanding how to calculate these kinds of expectations involving random matrices and vectors. Would you happen to know of any?

Comment: Understood.  I'm sure some textbooks emphasize this kind of matrix calculation, but no name springs to mind.  (I also apologize for the typos in my previous comment.  I meant $\operatorname{tr}(AB)=\operatorname{tr}(BA)$.)

Comment: No problem thanks again for help on this post and a previous one (with a similar calculation).

Comment: Sorry I just have one more question if you don't mind? Would this procedure work similarly if I wanted to find $\mathbb{E}[|\langle a,c \rangle|^4]?$

Comment: The matrix product looks icky.  Instead, conditional on $c$, the inner product $V = \langle a,c\rangle$ is $N(0,\| c\|^2)$ distributed, and hence $EV^4 =3 \|c\|^4.$  Now take the expectation of $\|c\|^4$ with a slightly more elaborate calculation.  If you know that $\|c\|^2$ has a $\chi-$squared distribution you can recite known facts to skip some of the calculus.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63248/discussion-between-xk3-and-kimchi-lover).